# I18n.locale troubles when sorting datas from a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, internationalization, locale

I have a little problem with my application rails and locale params.

I successfully enabled all my controllers' routes in the routes.rb file with my :locale value between domain and controller in the URL.

When the controller need to show a sorting of many datas from one Table with the method "Data.find(:all)" or "Data.all" or custom condition to see all, I get a routing error.

If there is only une data filtered by an ID or ONE parameter to render only ONE data, all works fine.

In the logs I only see "500 internal error" and the error as I see on my site (development mod).

Here is the full error code:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"translation_english_words", :locale=>#<TranslationEnglishWord id: 1, data: "song", transvalue: "choubidoubop">}
```

The URL is: "http://domain/fr/translation_english_words" (:domain/:locale/:controller)

My controller is **"translation_english_words"** and has a table with same name in my database.

The table has 3 column, id:autoincrement, data:string, transvalue:string

I saw the part **":locale"** in the route doesn't contain the **"fr"** or **"en"** or other locale is must contain. and it just not contain data begining with **"** and finishing with **"** as all other params like **":action"** and **":controller"**

Actually I need locale just for detect the wished language.

Not using any "t(:value)" for translation atm.

This error is not only on this controller, but on EACH controllers that require sorting more than one UNIQUE scoped data from any table.

Someone have any idea about how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok everyone, I found "why" the route failed.

It seem this caused the route to break:

Controller:

```
<pre>
    def index
    @translation_english_word = TranslationEnglishWord.all
    end
</pre>
```

View:

```
<pre>
    &lt;% for translation_english_word in @translation_english_word %&gt;
    &lt;%= link_to "Edit", 
    edit_translation_english_word_path(translation_english_word) %&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
    &lt;% end %&gt;
    &lt;%= link_to "New English Translation", new_translation_english_word_path %&gt;
</pre>
```

The paths that call `edit_translation_english_word_path` and `new_translation_english_word_path` seem to break the route.
I don't know Why, but removing them, resolved my issue, but it still isn't clear why this  happens, and I'd like to understand why if anyone can comment to me?

Answer (score 1):

would be great to know the actual implementation of your routes, [have you followed the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params)? seems you should have something like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
scope "/:locale" do
  resources :translation_english_words
  # [...] # all other controllers
end
```

I'm not sure you

> successfully enabled all my controllers' routes in the routes.rb

In fact your controller is interpreted as locale, which makes me think that the routing attempt is different.

Also I can't really understand your url: `http://domain/fr/translation_english_words`
Shouldn't this be something like": `http://domain.lvh.me:3000/fr/translation_english_words` if you're working in a local development environment?

Comment: The controller isn't interpreted as locale, because if there is No value in the table _(I have 3 controllers like this one, french_words / german_words / english_words)_.

If there is One value, route fail.

If there is nothing in the table, route work.

and this part:
`:locale=>#<TranslationEnglishWord id: 1, data: "song", transvalue: "choubidoubop">`
It's not the controller, it's the first row of the Database's Table called TranslationEnglishWords _(autho generated with nifty:scaffold)_


When I say "domain" I mean the IP binding including the Port like: **"192.168.1.34:8082"**

Comment: for the routing, I used this:

`scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|fr|de/ do
  resources :translation_english_words
  # [...] * all other controllers
end`

And when typing `rake routes` I can see the route for `/:locale/translation_english_words` and all actions for the controller.